# Why is text in TextBox highlighted (selected) when form is displayed?

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I have a form containing a `TextBox` in C# which I set to a string as follows:

```
textBox.Text = str;
```

When the form is displayed, why does the text in the texbox appear highlighted/selected?

Comment: Your question might be related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140250/how-to-remove-focus-from-a-textbox-in-c-winforms

Comment: Did you manage to sort this out? How did you fix this?

Comment: @fletcher: I haven't got round to looking at it yet. I'll award the answer in a few days.

Comment: You can add a vb.net tag, since the issue is really the same and accepted answer is valid too

Comment: BenSmith's answer related to viewing Tab Order will be very useful in such a this scenario.

Answer (score 151, accepted):

The text box has a `TabIndex` of 0 and `TabStop` set to true. This means that the control will be given focus when the form is displayed.

You can either give another control the 0 `TabIndex` (if there is one) and give the text box a different tab index (>0), or set `TabStop` to false for the text box to stop this from happening.

Comment: Are you sure that textbox TabIndex is set to 0? It comes out of its behaviour?

Comment: @26071986 - Well, I ran a quick test. If, on a form with one text box and a button, I change the text within the textbox in the constructor when the tabindex is set to 0 the text is highlighted. If the button has the 0 tab index and the textbox tabindex is >0, the text is not highlighted.

Comment: It does indeed seem to be to do with TabIndex - only I changed all my elements tab indices appropriately (so I thought). Turns out that Groups have tab indices too which you need to change as well as all their containing elements. So whilst I'd set up element tabs from 1-9, a group still had 0, so the text box in that group became the first activated element (hence had its contents highlighted).

Comment: It is not necessarily related to having TabIndex = 0, but it certainly happens if the TextBox has the LOWEST TabIndex of the form. To verify: set TabIndex = 5 in the TextBox and set a number greater then 5 in all the TabIndexs of the other controls of the form.

Comment: This also happens when you select a new TabPage in a TabControl. The same solution works.

Comment: Thanks! I just needed to change the ```TabStop``` property from ```True``` -> ```False``` then, everything is solved. 

Answer (score 48):

The default behavior of a TextBox in Windows Forms is to highlight all of the text if it gets focused for the first time by tabbing into it, but not if it is clicked into. We can see this in Reflector by looking at the `TextBox`'s `OnGotFocus()` override:

```
protected override void OnGotFocus(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnGotFocus(e);
    if (!this.selectionSet)
    {
        this.selectionSet = true;
        if ((this.SelectionLength == 0) && (Control.MouseButtons == MouseButtons.None))
        {
            base.SelectAll();
        }
    }
}
```

It's that if statement that is causing the behavior that we don't like. Furthermore, to add insult to injury, the `Text` property's setter blindly resets that `selectionSet` variable whenever the text is re-assigned:

```
public override string Text
{
    get
    {
        return base.Text;
    }
    set
    {
        base.Text = value;
        this.selectionSet = false;
    }
}
```

So if you have a TextBox and tab into it, all the text will be selected. If you click into it, the highlight is removed, and if you re-tab into it, your caret position (and selection length of zero) is preserved. But if we programmatically set new `Text`, and tab into the TextBox again, then all of the text will be selected again.

If you are like me and find this behavior annoying and inconsistent, then there are two ways around this problem.

The first, and probably the easiest, is to simply trigger the setting of `selectionSet` by calling `DeselectAll()` on form `Load()` and whenever the `Text` changes:

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);

    this.textBox2.SelectionStart = this.textBox2.Text.Length;
    this.textBox2.DeselectAll();
}
```

(`DeselectAll()` just sets `SelectionLength` to zero. It's actually `SelectionStart` that flips the `TextBox`'s `selectionSet` variable. In the above case, the call to `DeselectAll()` is not necessary since we are setting the start to the end of the text. But if we set it to any other position, like the start of the text, then calling it is a good idea.)

The more permanent way is to create our own TextBox with the desired behavior through inheritance:

```
public class NonSelectingTextBox : TextBox
{
    // Base class has a selectionSet property, but its private.
    // We need to shadow with our own variable. If true, this means
    // "don't mess with the selection, the user did it."
    private bool selectionSet;

    protected override void OnGotFocus(EventArgs e)
    {
        bool needToDeselect = false;

        // We don't want to avoid calling the base implementation
        // completely. We mirror the logic that we are trying to avoid;
        // if the base implementation will select all of the text, we
        // set a boolean.
        if (!this.selectionSet)
        {
            this.selectionSet = true;

            if ((this.SelectionLength == 0) && 
                (Control.MouseButtons == MouseButtons.None))
            {
                needToDeselect = true;
            }
        }

        // Call the base implementation
        base.OnGotFocus(e);

        // Did we notice that the text was selected automatically? Let's
        // de-select it and put the caret at the end.
        if (needToDeselect)
        {
            this.SelectionStart = this.Text.Length;
            this.DeselectAll();
        }
    }

    public override string Text
    {
        get
        {
            return base.Text;
        }
        set
        {
            base.Text = value;

            // Update our copy of the variable since the
            // base implementation will have flipped its back.
            this.selectionSet = false;
        }
    }
}
```

You maybe tempted to just not call `base.OnGotFocus()`, but then we would lose useful functionality in the base `Control` class. And you might be tempted to not mess with the `selectionSet` nonsense at all and simply deselect the text every time in OnGotFocus(), but then we would lose the user's highlight if they tabbed out of the field and back.

Ugly? You betcha. But it is what it is.

Answer (score 35):

The answers to this question helped me a lot with a similar problem, but the simple answer is only hinted at with a lot of other complex suggestions. Just set `SelectionStart` to `0` after setting your Text. Problem solved!

Example:

```
yourtextbox.Text = "asdf";
yourtextbox.SelectionStart = 0;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also choose the tab order for your form's controls by opening:

View->Tab Order

*Note that this option is only available in "View" if you have the Form design view open.*

Selecting "Tab Order" opens a view of the Form which allows you to choose the desired tab order by clicking on the controls.

Comment: This helped me much. Actually tab index doesn't matter if we concern on tab order.

Answer (score 1):

To unhighlight a text field, with VS 2013, try init with:

```
myTextBox.GotFocus += new System.EventHandler(this.myTextBox_GotFocus);
```

And add the method:

```
public void myTextBox_GotFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myTextBox.SelectionLength=0;
}
```

Comment: This would cause the text to be deselected if you previously focused the text box, selected some text in it, moved away from it and then focused it again.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this on C# but I ran into the same issue using a C++ WIN32 dialog box. Is seems like you can change the behavior by returning `FALSE` from `OnInitDialog()` or `WM_INITDIALOG`. Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't think this will help much, as the windows API is encapsulated inside winforms.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me

```
public void SetNotes(string notes)
    {
        notesTextBox.Text = notes;

        notesTextBox.Select();
        notesTextBox.SelectionLength = 0;
        notesTextBox.SelectionStart = notes.Length;//place cursor at end of text
    }
```