# c# how to catch mouse event outside textbox

Tags: c#

i need to hide a ListBox when I focus out a textbox. if i click on a different control or use Tab key then the textbox's "Leave" event occurs. But if I click inside the form, on any free space, then focusout doesn't happen. i saw something called mouse capture but i cant implement it.
[image]

i tried this:

```
private void txtProduct_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listProduct.Show();
    UIElement el = (UIElement)sender;
    el.CaptureMouse();
}  

private void MouseClickedElseWhere(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Clicks >= 1)
    {
        txtProduct_Leave(sender, new EventArgs());
    }
}

private void txtProduct_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listProduct.Hide();
}
```

but obviously it shows error. how do i achieve this? any help?

Comment: Did you try other [suggestions,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6489032/wpf-remove-focus-when-clicking-outside-of-a-textbox)  [similar to yours on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208356/how-to-deselect-textbox-if-user-clicks-elsewhere-on-the-form) ?

Comment: Try `txtbox_Leave` function.

Comment: yah I have tried every possible suggestions I could find. nothing worked. Please see my edited code.

Answer (score 0):

I had to make click event for my groupboxes even if groupbox doesnt have a click event by default.

```
//my_page.designer.cs  
this.groupBox2.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.groupBox2_clicked);  

//my_page.cs  
private void groupBox2_clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listProduct.Hide();
}
```