# textbox not losing focus

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, drawing

I have a Form which covers the entire screen. I have a `textbox` on it which is normally hidden but appears when a user clicks, drags mouse and then leaves. After that user can enter any value in the text box. Once entered, ideally user should be able to click outside of textbox and then the normal service should resume.

By normal service I mean that form should start getting all the events. What I have done so far is that on TextBox's KeyDown event; when Escape key is pressed, I have set the focus to the main form like this:

```
this.Focus(); //where this is mainform.
```

But this doesn't seem to work since `Textbox` still keeps receiving all the keys. I have a `KeyDown` event handler both for `Form` and `Textbox` and I have checked that all the `KeyDown` events pass on to the TextBox. I have a `TextBox` Leave event Handler as well which never gets called.

This `TextBox` is the only control on the form and the main form is used for drawing shapes (if that matters).

So, how can I make this `TextBox` lose focus when user clicks outside of it.

Comment: This question was answered here : [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140250/how-to-remove-focus-from-a-textbox-in-c-winforms][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140250/how-to-remove-focus-from-a-textbox-in-c-winforms

Comment: follow @mmorel1's links, you need to have another control thats visible=true but is out of the forms bounds. eg Textbox1.Left=-20;

Comment: @Jeremy Thompson: In that case, the focus will shift to that Textbox and my main form will stop receiving keys. for example, on Escape button on mainform, I hide the form. That wouldn't be possible. Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

if it works like in VB, for what I remember, try to set the form property `KeyPreview` to false so all keys will be passed only to the focused control on the form.

Comment: By default, the KeyPreview is False which means that Keys are not previewed by the parent i.e., mainform. I tried setting it to True but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

If you set your form [KeyPreview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview.aspx) property to true, your form has first chance to handle any keystrokes that you make. If it is something you want to handle i.e. escape as in your comment above, handle it in your form's KeyDownEvent and mark it as handled so your textbox will not see it.

From above Msdn Page:

> When this property is set to true, the form will receive all KeyPress, KeyDown, and KeyUp events. After the form's event handlers have completed processing the keystroke, the keystroke is then assigned to the control with focus.

Answer (score 0):

I guess back in '11 this didn't work, but now

```
this.ActiveControl = null;
```

works fine. However if you intend to use Tab to cycle controls, focusing a label with suitable TabIndex is the way.