# Change the default selected item to none

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer, selecteditem

I have a `WindowsForm` that contains a lot of `UserControl`.
Each `UserControl` has a `PictureBox`, a few `TextBox` and a `Button`.

As soon as  my program loads, my first `TextBox` is Highlighted in blue and I don't want that.

In fact I don't want anything to be selected at all.(`Buttons`, `TextBox` etc..)
I've looked into the properties but I can't find exactly how to totally remove this 'Feature'.
All my `TextBox` are `ReadOnly` but can become `Write/Read` while the program is running.

Any Idea how i could do this ?

Thanks in advance.

---

Update

Changing the `TabStop` properties to false did part of the job since it doesn't allow selection with tab at all. But I don't want to block the user from using tab to navigate between boxes I just don't want any selection when I run the program. Is there another way ?

Thanks for your time again.

Comment: check in constructor, when all the controls are initialized

Comment: I've never really played with the Designer.. 
What should I be looking for ?
In the mainform designer or the usercontrol designer?

Comment: check the usercontrol designer, it may by there...

Comment: @Sam1 I'm still searching in it although the TextBox with the selection problem is declared exactly like all the others.

The only difference is that it is the first of the texbox (on top) and as `MultiLine` set to true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On form Load set Focus to any label or any other control which is not tab stop on the form

> ```
> private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)  
> { 
>   this.ActiveControl = label1;       
> }
> ```
>
> [How to remove the focus from a TextBox in WinForms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140250/how-to-remove-focus-from-a-textbox-in-c-winforms)

Comment: What is the problem with this statement.. it not Control TabStop Set Focus on the Form's First label

Comment: Yes!! Setting ActiveControl to an invisible label did it ! Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

You need to set TabFocus to false for textboxes etc

```
//textBox1.TabFocus = false;

textBox1.TabStop = false;
```

Comment: I can't find this property with this syntax and in the property sheet.

Do I need to add a specific Using statement on top?

Comment: oh and fogot to mention my textbox are readonly ill update my question

Answer (score 0):

comboBoxName.SelectedIndex = -1;

Comment: It is usually a good idea to write a little sentence that explains your answer, even if just a courtesy. :-)