# Figure out that one Textbox is losing focus and other control will be focused

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, textbox

So basically I have two Textboxes: LoginEmail and LoginPassword. I am trying to set animation for them:

- User enter LoginEmail #1 animation #1 starts, user quit LoginEmail #1 animation #2 starts
- User enter LoginEmail #1 animation #1 starts, user quit LoginEmail #1 and go LoginPassword #2 there is no animation

## Code

```
private void LoginEmail_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    FocusAnimation.Begin();
}

private void LoginEmail_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    UnfocusAnimation.Begin();
}

private void LoginPassword_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    FocusAnimation.Begin();
}

private void LoginPassword_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    UnfocusAnimation.Begin();
}
```

It's now not working, because when user enter LoginEmail #1 and then go to LoginPassword #2 there are events:

- LoginEmail_GotFocus (=> FocusAnimation.Begin();)
- LoginEmail_LostFocus (=> UnfocusAnimation.Begin();)
- LoginPassword_GotFocus (=> FocusAnimation.Begin();)

So there is necessary to figure out that user is going from LoginEmail to LoginPassword and not showing UnfocusAnimation & 2nd FocusAnimation. Unfortunately I don't know the way to do it.

Comment: The question is not clear. The identifiers in the code don't match the identifiers in the text of the question (Textbox #1, LoginPassword, ...) You should also provide enough code to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Ok. Sorry I just updated my question.

Comment: you're still not providing enough code to reproduce the problem...

Comment: You can use any animation that you want. The problem is not animation, but that now I have lost focus event bind to animation, but sometimes that animation shouldn't be fired. So I need a better solution for that to avoid animation when user is selecting LoginPassword from LoginEmail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check who gets the focus after the LoginEmail TextBox.
Something like that should work:

```
private void LoginEmail_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
      var focusedControl = FocusManager.GetFocusedElement(this);
      if (focusedControl.GetType() != typeof(TextBox) || ((TextBox)focusedControl).Name != "LoginPassword")
      {
           UnfocusAnimation.Begin();            
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply get the focus for your `Textbox`1 whenever any key is being pressed in the `keyboard` like :

```
yourtextbox.Focus();
```

and then for losing the `focus` you can use something like this:

```
this.Focus();
```

Have a look at these for more:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/

[How to remove the focus from a TextBox in WinForms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140250/)

Comment: No it's not what's question about. I updated question, because it was unclear.