# Setting Focus on another control on button click

Tags: c#, winforms, button

When I click on a button it will keep selected what can I do to deselect the button after click? See the image bellow:

[image: Button start is selected how to remove the selection after click?]

Comment: is this a windows application or web application ?

Comment: @PranavPatel windows app

Comment: Try `this.ActiveControl = <Any control other than Start button";`.

Comment: only one way, after click put focus on another control

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove the focus from a TextBox in WinForms?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140250/how-to-remove-the-focus-from-a-textbox-in-winforms)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need some other focusable control to move the focus to like your `StopButton`.

you can set    `btnStop.Focus () ;`

You can also set the forms activecontrol property to null like

```
 this.ActiveControl = null;
```

Or using Tab order after set up order :

```
SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
```

Answer (score 8):

[**Focus Method**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.focus(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    btnStop.Focus(); //setting the focus on Stop Button

    // ...your code
}
```

[**ActiveControl Property**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.containercontrol.activecontrol(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.ActiveControl = btnStop; //setting the focus on Stop Button

    // ...your code
}
```

[**SelectNextControl Method**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.selectnextcontrol.aspx)

```
private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Control p;
    p = ((Button)sender).Parent;
    p.SelectNextControl(ActiveControl, true, true, true, true);

    // ...your code
}
```

Comment: I'd like to add something. When embedding UserControl in TabControl requesting focus by userCtrl.Focus() always returns false and focus isn't transferred. But setting this.ActiveControl works flawlessly.