# How do I set focus to a Usercontrol

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I have 50 UserControls that I add to a flowlayoutPanel dynamically.
I need to set focus to a user control but it doesn't work.
I have been searching a lot but can't find any example that I understand.

The only example that I find is this
[Setting Focus to a .NET UserControl...?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2362428/setting-focus-to-a-net-usercontrol)

I tried to use userCtrl.Focus(); but it didn't work.
As I have been reading the usercontrol doesn't like to have focus.

Comment: Do the `UserControls` contain other controls?  If so, you could focus one of those.

Comment: this.ActiveControl = YourControl;

Comment: Set ActiveControl as others have commented. Additionally, they're your UserControls! If you give them a public FocusOnMe() method and code that method to set focus where you will, then your form could say myUserControl.FocusOnMe().

Comment: UserControl really despises getting the focus and tries as hard as it can to avoid it.  Passing it off to a child control whenever it can.  It does not have any use for focus, it cannot tell the user that it has the focus and has no use for keyboard input whatsoever.  Which begs the question why you are trying to fight it, very unclear from the question.  Your other question about it suggests that you actually want the FLP to have the focus.  It doesn't like it either.  Giving FLP focus requires surgery [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3562449/17034).

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37589814/setting-focus-on-another-control-on-button-click/37590498#37590498) out.

Answer (score 6):

> Addition: Now that I understand more of the `Control` class, I
>   understand that if you derive from `Control` you should not subscribe
>   to its events, but use the On.. functions, like `OnEnter`. I've
>   changed my answer accordingly

To Activate any `Control`, including a `UserControl` use `Control.Select()`.

If you do this for a `TextBox`, you'll see that `Select` ensures that it gets the input focus.

I guess you want to do something with the selected `UserControl` (the `Control` that has the focus), for instance, you want to change its appearance, or select any of the controls on it. To do this, your `UserControl` class has to subscribe to the events Control.Enter and Control.Leave

I have created a `UserControl` with a `CheckBox` that is automatically checked whenever the `UserControl` is selected (has the input focus):

**Addition: If you derive from a Control, don't subscribe to events `Enter` and `Leave`. Instead override the functions that raise these events:** [OnEnter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onenter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) / [OnLeave](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onleave(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnEnter(EventArgs e)
    {
        this.checkBox1.Checked = true;
        base.OnEnter(e); // this will raise the Enter event
    }

    protected override void OnLeave(EventArgs e)
    {
        this.checkBox1.Checked = false;
        base.OnLeave(e); // this will raise the Leave event
    }
}
```

I have a form with a button, and an event handler that is called when the button is clicked:

```
private void OnButton1Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.userControl1.Select();
}
```

Now whenever the button is clicked I see that the user control gets the focus because the check box is checked and whenever I click elsewhere the checkbox is unchecked.

Answer (score 2):

You can set focus to a control by using the [ActiveControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.containercontrol.activecontrol(v=vs.110).aspx) Property

```
this.ActiveControl = myUserControl;
```

Answer (score 2):

Though you did not detail what did you mean it did not work, focusing has many aspects conventionally.

**1. Explicit focusing**

Calling `Focus()` method of a control is the same as setting `ActiveControl` of the container form. If `CanFocus` returns true (your control and all its parents are visible and enabled), it works; however, you will have no visual feedback, except some indirect hint, eg. the originally focused control (button or textbox) loses the focus.

To visualize the focused state you might want to use some custom paint:

```
protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.Clear(Focused ? SystemColors.Highlight : SystemColors.Control);
}
```

If you derive directly from `Control` instead of `UserControl`, override the following two methods to force a repaint on changing the focused state:

```
protected override void OnGotFocus(EventArgs e)
{
    Invalidate();
    base.OnGotFocus(e);
}

protected override void OnLostFocus(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLostFocus(e);
    Invalidate();
}
```

**2. Focusing by the mouse**

To receive focus by clicking the control add this line to the constructor:

```
SetStyle(ControlStyles.Selectable, true);
```

If you derive directly from `Control` instead of `UserControl`, override the `OnMouseDown`, too:

```
protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (!Focused)
        Focus();
    base.OnMouseDown(e);
}
```

**3. Focusing by the keyboard**

To receive focus by the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key just set the `TabStop` property to `true` and adjust the `TabOrder` property.

Answer (score 0):

Example to focus on textBox1:

```
textBox1.Select();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try tab index of the user control. If you set its tab index to 1 it will be focused once the program start.