# C# disable textbox focus on form load

Tags: c#, forms

**I have a textbox which I want to disable focus for it
How do I disable focus for Textbox with Programming**

disable textbox focus using programming c# ,
I have used below two codes not working:

```
textBox1.focus()=false;

textBox1.focused()=false;
```

Comment: please check this link help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140250/how-to-remove-the-focus-from-a-textbox-in-winforms

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Random number generator only generating one random number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767999/random-number-generator-only-generating-one-random-number)

Answer (score 0):

You can set `this.ActiveControl = null;` with this is your Form

```
private void YourForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{ 
    this.ActiveControl = null;       
}
```