# How to change focus on a groupbox click?

Tags: c#, forms, click

I'm trying to reset the focus when clicking outside a textbox placed inside a groupbox. What is the best way to do so? As I saw right there is no such event like mouseclick/click for a groupbox.

It should move the focus when a click is done, not when the mouse leaves the box or anything similar.

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: See following : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140250/how-to-remove-the-focus-from-a-textbox-in-winforms

Comment: @jdweng that does not answer my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As I saw right there is no such event like mouseclick/click for a
> groupbox.

Here's a LITERAL answer to your problem.

In the `Load()` event of your Form, cast the GroupBox back to the generic [Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control?view=net-5.0) class so you can wire up the [Click()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.click?view=net-5.0) event (or a similar event from the ones available):

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ((Control)groupBox1).Click += Ctl_Click;
}

private void Ctl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Focus();
}
```

Or with an anonymous delegate so you don't need the separate helper method:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ((Control)groupBox1).Click += (s2, e2) => { textBox1.Focus(); };
}
```

Comment: Amazing. Thank you, great answer, didn't know you can do that.

Comment: I have been doing this for a long time (20+ years) and hadn't thought of that one. Clever.

Comment: @JesseChunn It's always fun finding a piece of code on SO that does something in a completely different way than you're used to seeing.